# How can I initialize a repaint timer from a static context?

Tags: java, swing, timer, draw, actionevent

After some reading I am back to trying to make these drawings move. Where I am having difficulty is that the timer is never started - when I try to run the initGame method it tells me I can't reference it from a static context. If not the main loop, then where do I start this? I have been able to make it start in drawComponent, but that is just creating a new timer every time it draws which is no good.

Main class:

```
public class Test2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel paintPanel;
    public Test2() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        paintPanel = new  PaintPanel();
        getContentPane().add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }
    class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        private List<Shape> gladiators;
        private Shape mouseOverShape=null;
        private Timer timer;

        public void initGame() {

            timer = new Timer(50, this);
            timer.start();

        }       
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
                        // change object location here
            System.out.println("Repainting");
        }

            public PaintPanel(){
            super();

            // Create my Gladiator objects and add them here?

        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            for (Shape s : gladiators){
                g2.draw(s);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Test2 gamePanel = new Test2();
                gamePanel.setVisible(true);
                PaintPanel.initGame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Gladiator class:

```
public class Gladiator implements Drawable{


        int[] location = new int[] {25,25};

        public void Draw(Graphics g){
               // draw out the shapes which constitute each "gladiator"
    }

}
```

I have also included some quote lines which indicate where I assume other actions go. I would appreciate any feedback on any major problems with those or other concepts. Thanks all!

Edit:

Following Hovercraft Full of Eels suggestion I moved the declaration of the method from inside the main method to inside of the Test2 method... I also changed a capitalization error. It now looks like this:

```
public Test2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    paintPanel = new  PaintPanel();
    getContentPane().add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();

    paintPanel.initGame();  
}
```

Main method is the same, minus the "PaintPanel.initGame();".

I get a cannot find symbol error referring to initGame.

2nd Edit:

I think my question was answered. I will make another edit if I still have questions or mark this answered in a bit. Thanks, Hovercraft!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you call `initGame()`? Since the timer is started in this method, if you never call it, the Timer never starts.

Regarding:

> when I try to run the initGame method it tells me I can't reference it from a static context

You need to show us this attempt. Usually this means that you're trying to call the method on the class not on the instance.

i.e.,

```
public Test2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    paintPanel = new  PaintPanel();
    getContentPane().add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();

    paintPanel.initGame();  
}
```

---

**Edit**

You state:

```
PaintPanel.initGame();
```

You can't do this. You can't call a non-static method on a class as if it's a static method. Instead it must be called on the instance as I show above. So the answer to the question,

> How can I initialize a repaint timer from a static context?

Is that you don't. You initialize it from a **non**-static context.

Note that you shouldn't declare the paintPanel variable as a JPanel since you need to call the `initGame()` method on it which is not a method of JPanel. Instead declare it as a PaintPanel variable.

---

**Edit 2**

regarding:

> I get a cannot find symbol error referring to initGame.

Please re-read the last paragraph above this edit.

Comment: I call it in the main method. I will add it back in for clarity.

Comment: Okay, I get what you are saying now

Comment: @PeterF: Please read my edits. Again, if a change shows an error, then show the new code as an edit to your original question, usually as additional code and information at the bottom, so we can see exactly what you're doing and exactly what errors Java is giving you.

Comment: My apologies, Hovercraft. I do now see that I was capitalizing the first and second word so it was still calling the class, not the instance. I do have a new error, will post it in a second.

Comment: @PeterF: see **Edit 2** and the paragraph above it.

Comment: Yes, I think we have been out of sync is all. Thanks